# CMake-generated XCode project won't compile

Tags: xcode, cmake

Having generated an XCode project using `cmake -GXcode`, XCode refuses to load it (without saying why) and from the command line `xcodebuild` refuses to build it:

```
2013-12-04 19:03:24.317 xcodebuild[356:1007] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 3073. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
2013-12-04 19:03:24.329 xcodebuild[356:1007] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 3073. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
2013-12-04 19:03:24.331 xcodebuild[356:1007] Unexpected character / at line 1
xcodebuild: error: Unable to read project 'MegaGlest.xcodeproj'.
Reason: Project /Users/wil/Code/Hobby/Glest/MegaGlest/MegaGlest.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed.
```

The head of MegaGlest.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj is:

```
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
       archiveVersion = 1;
       classes = {
       };
       objectVersion = 46;
       objects = {

/* Begin PBXAggregateTarget section */
              CEDDE5554807461083D7FF4B /* ALL_BUILD */ = {
                     isa = PBXAggregateTarget;
                     buildConfigurationList = F76CEFDA8B3B43859E2BEA04 /* Build configuration list for PBXAggregateTarget "ALL_BUILD" */;
                     buildPhases = (
                            2D1DC2B2C96847ACBBF3353B /* CMake Rules */,
                     );
                     dependencies = (
                            4DD382F4D3944F438BE79300 /* PBXTargetDependency */,
                            712654EAA2C04191A80DFC92 /* PBXTargetDependency */,
                            40FC4953D73F4B97AAB207EE /* PBXTargetDependency */,
                            6E22BB74457F4E16B1BEE0A9 /* PBXTargetDependency */,
```

Software versions:

XCode Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)

cmake version 2.8.10.2

How can you get cmake to create a project compatible with XCode, or XCode to load a project created by cmake?

Comment: Head of `project.pbxproj` looks fine (comparing to mine version). Can you show `CMakeLists.txt`? xcodebuild complaining about line 3073, what code is there?